# jupyter notebook prints output even when suppressed

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

**Why is it printing the bins from the histogram?**
Shouldn't the semicolon suppress it?

In [1]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all";
```

In [2]

```
%matplotlib inline
data ={'first':np.random.rand(100), 
       'second':np.random.rand(100)}
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2)
for idx, k in enumerate(data):
    axes[idx].hist(data[k], bins=20);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set `InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all";`, so you've set all nodes to have ast interactivity enabled. So you get the values of  `data = {..}`

And `;` works only for the last **top level** expression,  `axes[idx].hist(data[k], bins=20);` is not a top level expression, as it is nested in the `for`, the last top level node is the `for`, which is a statement.

Simply add a last no-op statement, and end it with `;`

```
%matplotlib inline
data ={'first':np.random.rand(100), 
       'second':np.random.rand(100)};
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2);
for idx, k in enumerate(data):
    axes[idx].hist(data[k], bins=20)
pass; # or None; 0; "foo"; ...
```

And you won't have any outputs.

Use [codetransformer](https://github.com/llllllllll/codetransformer/) `%%ast` magic to quickly see the ast of an expression.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the documentation, you will see exactly what it returns - a three item tuple described below. You can display it in the notebook by placing a ? at the end of the call to the histogram. It looks like your `InteractiveShell` is making it display. Normally, yes a semicolon would suppress the output, although inside of a loop it would be unnecessary.

> ### Returns
>
> **n** : array or list of arrays
>       The values of the histogram bins. See **normed** and **weights**
>       for a description of the possible semantics. If input **x** is an
>       array, then this is an array of length **nbins**. If input is a
>       sequence arrays `[data1, data2,..]`, then this is a list of
>       arrays with the values of the histograms for each of the arrays
>       in the same order.
>
> **bins** : array
>       The edges of the bins. Length nbins + 1 (nbins left edges and right
>       edge of last bin).  Always a single array even when multiple data
>       sets are passed in.
>
> **patches** : list or list of lists
>       Silent list of individual patches used to create the histogram
>       or list of such list if multiple input datasets.